# What is the difference between Proxy and Channnel in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf

What is the difference between Proxy and Channels in WCF?

**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/558163/Difference-between-Proxy-and-Channel-Factory-in-WC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion about WCF Channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201120/confusion-about-wcf-channels)